# Cloud Build Trigger Settings have stale, out-of-date GitHub branch data

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

We installed the Google Cloud Build GitHub app. We then created some Build Triggers with the Google Cloud Build web user interface. This worked for a while.

Recently we pushed new branches to our GitHub repositories and tried to create Google Cloud Build Triggers for those branches. The Trigger Settings page says "No branch matches" even though we are 100% sure that the branch exists on GitHub.

[image]

**How can we refresh the branch listings in the Google Cloud Build Trigger Settings page?**

We have tried logging in/out of Google Cloud Build and GitHub. We have also tried uninstalling and re-installing the Google Cloud Build GitHub app. We have also tried simply waiting for a few hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that, while configuring Cloud Build with GitHub, we had pushed too many buttons.

This is an overview of what we needed to reset.

In **GitHub**

1. Go to the affected repository.
2. Open its settings.
3. Delete the **Webhook** associated with `source.developers.google.com/webhook/github`.
4. Delete the **Deploy key** associated with Google Connected Repository Fingerprint.

In **Google Cloud Console** (console.cloud.google.com)

1. Open **Source Repositories**
2. Disconnect the mirror of the affected repository.
3. Open **Cloud Build**
4. Delete and recreate the Build Trigger(s) for the affected repository.

---

Aside re: the **Google Cloud Build GitHub App**

Setting up specific triggers in Google Cloud Build is orthogonal to using the Google Cloud Build GitHub app. The former does not require the latter. They are different ways to do similar things.

If you had installed the Google Cloud Build GitHub App in your GitHub account because you thought it was required for Google Cloud Build Triggers, then uninstall the Google Cloud Build GitHub App. It works differently than setting up specific Google Cloud Build triggers does, and I found it quite confusing to have both running.